# KafkaStreams applications

Tags: stream, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I run two kafka streams applications separately, each one in a different JVM instance and they are working fine. Once I run the applications in the same JVM instance, the second application is not working (neither consuming nor producing data). Are there any limitations about running two separate apps in the same JVM instance? Does this also happen for kafka consumers?

Answer (score 0):

It should work to put multiple `KafkaStreams` instances into the same JVM. But it might be easier to just increase the number of thread within one instance.

Note: the number of thread over all instances that you can utilize is limited by the number of input partitions of you input topics (this is not quite exact but a good rule of thumb). Do you have enough partitions in your input topic? Do you see that some partitions are not assigned to an instance an not processed?

Also note, Kafka Stream parallelizes per threads -- this means, if you have 2 instances with 2 threads each, and only 2 input topic partitions, it can happen that both partitions are assigned to the two thread of one instance while the two thread of the other instance are idle. During runtime, we only "see" thread and don't know if they run within the same or different `KafkaStreams` instances.